# Single word for "division" into all possible cases for analysis

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good word for the act of "division into cases"?

This as in, for example, analyzing and enumerating all the possible cases and possibility of a situation, or in math proofs where one exhaust all possible values of a variable.

I can think of "categorize" or "classify". But I am not satisfied with them because them don't express the idea of identifying each *individual* possibility at the finest granularity.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case you aren't aware, this sort of proof is sometimes known as a [Proof by Exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion).

My first suggestion adds little to your question, as you've used the word yourself, but I'd simply say **dividing**: The problem to be addressed is **divided** or **sub-divided** into cases. (See also **break** and **break down**.)

> **divide**
>   divided; dividing *transitive verb*
>
> - to separate into two or more parts, areas, or groups (e.g. divide the city into wards)
> - to separate into classes, categories, or divisions (e.g. divide history into epochs)
> - cleave, part (e.g. a ship dividing the waves)

from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divide)

If the cases fall into very natural divisions, then those cases may instead be **enumerated**:

> **enumerate**
>   enumerated; enumerating *transitive verb*
>
> - to ascertain the number of :  count
> - to specify one after another :  list

from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enumerate)

Another nice alternative is the **delineation** of cases:

> **delineate**
>
> - Describe or portray (something) precisely.
> - Indicate the exact position of (a border or boundary)

from [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/delineate)

For something more "arty" you might say that the logical space is **carved** into distinct cases:

> **carve**
>   carved; carving *transitive verb*
>
> - to cut with care or precision (e.g. carved fretwork)
> - to make or get by or as if by cutting —often used with out (e.g. carve out a career)
> - to cut into pieces or slices (e.g. carved the turkey)

from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carve)

Some other potentially useful words, though I'm less convinced, are **dissect**, **atomize** and **anatomize**.

Comment: Since my initial answer mostly used words that already appeared in the question, I've expanded it further.

Comment: 'enumeration of cases' or 'proof by cases' is usually what it's called in practice. 'proof by exhaustion' might be the title of the wiki article but I rarely see that used anymore.

Comment: Since my last comment, there has been some tidying, and the addition of a few further options, perhaps most notably the addition of **break**, as in "we **break** the problem into three cases".

Answer (score 0):

you also can use:  assort , categorize , pigeonhole , separate , sort

Comment: This would be a better answer with some references.

Answer (score 0):

The word **quantized** might fit, as it suggests that there is a definable minimum size.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quantize):

> **quantize**
>
> quantized; quantizing: *transitive* verb
>
> 1 :  to subdivide (something, such as energy) into small but
>   measurable increments

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about something that would be visually represented as a **Tree Diagram** (**Tree Diagram Analysis**) although it's not clear from your question whether you are doing something like a **Fault Tree analysis** using **Boolean logic** or perhaps closer to a **Probability Tree** or perhaps closer to a **Decision Tree**.

You could shorten this idea to *tree analysis* or even just *tree* as in *I made a tree of the problem*.

You could also use *diagram* as in *I diagramed the problem* or *I made a diagram of the problem*.

You could also use "flow* or *flow analysis* and in *I flowed the problem* or *I made a flow analysis*.

Similar to *flow* I think *scheme* or *step-by-step* might also work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***elimination*** (*reasoning by elimination*).

freedictionary.org:

> **[elimination](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=elimination)**
>   *NOUN*
>   [Wordnet 3.0]
>
> **3.** analysis of a problem into alternative possibilities followed by the systematic rejection of unacceptable alternatives;
>   [syn:
>   elimination, reasoning by elimination]